# Reliable way to create a dir with perl?

Tags: linux, perl, mkdir

From the perl documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html it states:

> "The API was changed in the 2.0 branch. For a time, mkpath and rmtree
>   tried, unsuccessfully, to deal with the two different calling
>   mechanisms. This approach was considered a failure.
>
> The new semantics are now only available with make_path and
>   remove_tree . The old semantics are only available through mkpath and
>   rmtree. Users are strongly encouraged to upgrade to at least 2.08 in
>   order to avoid surprises."

Some of this stuff in perl just amazes me. What it appears to be saying is that if I can't control the version of perl (which I can't) then I don't really have any reliable way to do something as simple as create a dir. What I've found is that there is even more issues than what the documentation states as some of the parameter calls they specified are not supported.

Anyway, my question is, is there a reliable way to create a dir in perl, set the mask, username and group and have that work with older versions of perl? We are using 5.8.8

Comment: it says `mkpath` still exists, and i see no indication that it'll ever go away.  (perl values backwards compatibility like you wouldn't believe.)  so if upgrading `File::Path` is unfeasible, why not just use the older `mkpath`?

Comment: you can't control the version of perl, but you can certainly control the version of File::Path

Comment: @eevee. The bit that concerns me with mkpath is the statement "For a time, mkpath and rmtree tried, unsuccessfully, to deal with the two different calling mechanisms. This approach was considered a failure". So could I be using an interface that is considered a failure? Why was it considered a failure?

Comment: Some of this prejudiced antipathy towards Perl just amazes me, too.

Comment: @Borodin I am amazed that people will expect software that is 10 years old to work flawlessly.

Comment: @TLP: I believe the Perl 5 Porters try way too hard to maintain backward compatibility. It means there is little cost to failures like this and people start to blame the language instead of their own negligence; even when the perceived problem is an imaginary one! Running Perl v8 when the rest of the world will soon be on v18 is inexcusable.

Comment: @MikeKulls you misunderstand.  they decided they didn't like the argument style of `mkpath` and designed a new one.  they tried to make `mkpath` accept both styles of arguments, and it didn't work very well.  so they broke the new style out into a new function, `make_path`, and left `mkpath` as only accepting the old style as it had originally done.

Comment: @Eevee That's the bit that concerns me. If I go for compatibility I need to use mkpath but I've already found 1 case where mkpath does not follow the documentation, specifically where you specify a hash as the second parameter.

Comment: @Borodin. I use perl daily and do like it but is it really that amazing that people would think perl is less than perfect?

Comment: @MikeKulls: Being a man-made thing, yes of course Perl is less than perfect. But it is no worse than other programming languages, and yet seems to be fair game for unwarranted tribal negativism and criticism like yours. Most people who were having problems with a version of any other language that was seven years out of date would be apologetic and asking for a work-around. Not so with Perl, as it is the industry's whipping boy.

Comment: @borodin. I suggest there is good reason for this and if you think about it, in many ways it is far worse than other languages. It dawned on me one day when I was looking at some code and was thinking $@ was an array. I mean seriously, on what planet was calling a variable $@ considered a good idea? Don't get me wrong, I do like perl but I am getting sick of a lot of stuff in it.

Comment: @MikeKulls Since when is the sigil for arrays `$` in Perl? I doubt you will find any language where you can ignore its rules and still have it make sense.

Comment: @MikeKulls: Recognition of the built-in variables comes with familiarity, and `$@` is nowhere near as common as `$_` and `@_` which I presume you are comfortable with. Perl 4 was a comparatively clumsy language, and I think people's prejudices are based on that version and encouraged by major Unix releases being bundled with very out-of-date versions of Perl. Perl 5 version 10 had many major improvements, and everybody should run at least this release; but some aspects of Perl 4 endure because of compatibility concerns, and `$@` should really be hidden inside `Try::Tiny` to handle it properly.

Comment: @TLP. I got confused that I was looking at an array because the second chr was @. You could say this was my fault but it's at least partially the fault of whoever gave it such an unfriendly name.

Comment: @Borodin. We're going to get told off for having a conversation soon. My point was that you simply can't say these are good naming conventions. As you said, I should probably use Try::Tiny but this is another perl-ism. I'm sure there are other libraries also that do the same thing, all with their advantages and disadvantages. If I start using these then I will run into version issues I'm sure. If I was using C# there is only one way to handle an error (Try/Catch), in Perl I'm betting there would be a good 10.

Comment: @MikeKulls I find just about every single aspect of Perl perfectly logical. You look at the first character in a variable name to determine its type: `$` is scalar, which applies not only to names such as `$foo` or `$@`, but also the scalar version of `$array[1]` and `$hash{key}`. When you want a slice you do `@array[1,2,3]` or `@hash{1,2,3}`. Sure, there's the infamous Perl "magic" in many things, which adds to the learning curve, but the basics are really quite simple and consistent.

Comment: @MikeKulls As for [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), that is a Perl trademark, is it not? Some would say that having only one way to do something was a bad thing. And you should not confuse modules with Perl core functions. Modules are just free software, some of which are shipped with perl and some not.

Comment: @TLP As much as I like perl, there are many areas of it that are a long long way from perferctly logical. I mean $@ is just not logical and I don't think it's really reasonable to say otherwise. I could start listing many other areas but I'm sure you know how long that would go on for. Interestingly there is a module to make variables like $@ more readable, which is pretty much an admission that they are unreadable. I think the fact that perl is popular despite all of these issues says something about it's usefulness, I consider it to be a lot like html, very clunky but powerful.

Comment: @TLP No, I absolutely 100% prefer to have a single good way to do things. For example, I really dislike the unless statement and the ability to put if and unless at the end of the line. Basically there are 4 ways to write an if statement when 1 would suffice. This 1 way does pretty much every other language.

Comment: From perldoc perlvar on `$@`: `Mnemonic: Where was the syntax error "at"?`. I think it is good that one has the option to be brief, perl has many such features that reduces typing. It is a simple matter to look up the special variables in perldoc perlvar. Or the shortcut: `perldoc -v '$@'`. Also, since the special variables are made up of punctuation, there is a limited set of characters to use. What variable name would you have chosen? You can list as many areas as you like, and I will explain to you why you are wrong. :)

Comment: @MikeKulls Personally, I like the postscript syntax. `say for @array` or `print $foo if $bar` is wonderfully concise. You don't *have* to use the alternatives if you do not want to, so I am guessing that you are upset over this from reading other people's code. To this, I can only say that if you know the language, it is not a problem. There is more than one way to do it. Anyway... We probably should not discuss this further here in the comments.

Comment: @TLP "I will explain to you why you are wrong" Lol. Everything is of course a matter of opinion but there is no way I am simply wrong. Of course once you know these things you know them, but you need to spend time learning the oddities of perl as opposed to learning something more useful. In answer to your question $@ should have been called $error or simply lastError or maybe been a function getLastError, anything would have been better that $@. I much prefer to have a single good way to do things than 10 bad ways, which is what perl always seems to provide. (eg try/catch).

Comment: @MikeKulls Well, funny enough, back when I learned perl, it was said that it was designed to accommodate people with many different programming backgrounds, which is why there are many different ways to do things. It was supposed to be easy to get started with. I kind of like that, although you are of course correct in that it inevitably means that it is also harder to read. I am quite serious, though, I doubt there is any "illogical" features of Perl that you can show me that are not the result of poor programming or bad practice.

Comment: Of course no one ever mentions C and its ridiculous semantics for `for`, `extern` and `#include`. And you must *hate* English with a passion as there are countless ways to say identical things.

Comment: @TLP. I have already shown you $@. This is not in the slightest bit logical and it is not bad programming practice in perl. If I tried to use $@ as a variable in C# (assuming that would work) and put that on a C# forum, people would be up in arms with my poor variable naming standards. $@ is the sort of name that an obfuscator would name a variable to deliberately confuse people (these are available for C#). As I said before, don't get me wrong, I do like perl, I just see it for what it is. It's much like HTML very powerful but clunky.

Comment: @Borodin In C it's the define that I'm not a big fan of. As for english it's the only language I know so I think it's too ingrained in my mind for me to see it clearly. Much like TLP and perl.

Comment: @MikeKulls Actually, I see both English and Perl very clearly, they feel like second nature to me. I'm not sure why you don't see English clearly if it is your first language. If you can't think of anything else that's illogical about Perl, that's ok, that's actually the result I was expecting.

Comment: @TLP. I actually don't have space to list all of the illogical stuff about perl. Seriously, where would you like me to start?? Should we talk about the poor oop features?

Comment: @MikeKulls I'm sure there are other languages who are better at oop, but then again, perl is not an object oriented language, its a scripting language, where the oop functionality has been implemented. I think that is quite logical. What is it about oop you find confusing?

Comment: borodin my hat goes off to you for maintaining a logical discussion. @TLP you will just say anything to "win" the arguement in your mind. I mean do you seriously need me to explain what is wrong with the oop features of perl? Just look online, the shortcomings are very well documented.

Comment: @MikeKulls If you don't want to be challenged on your statements, then don't make them in the first place. I think it might be a good idea to cancel this discussion, as it no longer is (or perhaps ever was) constructive.

Comment: @TLP I don't mind being challenged on them as long as the replies makes sense. Take your latest reply and read it a couple of time. It looks like you've run out of real arguements and started saying I don't like to be challenged. You ignore valid points, intentially misunderstand, change the topic, pretend not to know what I'm talking about, use a technique called "attack the man not the arguement". You basically just say anything to "win" the arguement in your mind. You are right on one thing though, it is time to end this discussion.

Comment: @MikeKulls I'm sorry your feelings were hurt, but I do think you read way more into my words than what was actually there.

Comment: @TLP There you go again. My feeling were not hurt. I'm just suggesting your argumentitive techniques are lacking. Again, you simply ignored my reply and wrote something irrelevant. ie you again did again exactly what I said you had been doing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25636/discussion-between-mikekulls-and-tlp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File::Path 2.09 should install perfectly fine on 5.8.8

Comment: +1 for not giving me a hard time for using an old version of perl. In the end I just used mkpath because in a large company getting someone to update stuff is a big deal.

Comment: @MikeKulls No one gave you a hard time for using an old version of perl. You were criticized for blaming perl for the fact that your perl version is out of date.

Comment: @TLP. That is simply not true. I was blaming perl for making changes that were considered a failure, for making too many changes and also for its inaccurate documentation.

Comment: @MikeKulls Well, the problem only applies if you use old versions of that module. I just connected the dots for you there. How many changes are "too many" for a module that has been around since 1995?

Comment: @TLP I would describe too many changes as being when they decide something has an issue, make changes that also have issues and then have to change it again.

Comment: What's inaccurate about its documentation?

Comment: @ikegami The documentation states that I can pass a hash array to mkpath function to specify extra options such as the mask, group etc. This does not work. When I pass a hash array as specified it ignores all of the options and treats it as if I have just specified verbose = 1. So basically one of the overloads it says I can use does not exist.

Comment: @MikeKulls, What version of File::Path do you have?

Comment: And you're saying the docs for 1.08 say you can pass a hash as the 3rd arg?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25632/discussion-between-mikekulls-and-ikegami)

Answer (score 3):

The version of Perl has nothing to do with this. [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Path) is a *module* that provides the convenience function `mkpath` which creates all of the directories in a path in one call.

Your version of Perl is over seven years old and really should be updated, but even so the latest version of `File::Path` will install just fine. Perl has, and has always had, the built-in function [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) which will create a single directory.